# Activate and Desactivate GameObjects by toggles - Augmented Reality

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, artoolkit

I'm making an application with Augmented Reality using ArToolkit.

It's very simple.

I show some elements accord the toggle stage. Example, I've 3 elements

[image: 3 Elements]

When I run, one element is displayed. If I click in first `toggle` this element hide and the next element show. When I click in second `toggle` the previous element hide and the next is show.

In another words, when I run only the first element (Cube) is displayed. When I click in first  toggle, each element (cube, esphere, cilinder) is show:

**Step 1:**
[image: Step1]

**Step 2:**
[image: step2]

**Step 3:**
[image: step3]

This is my hierarchy:

[image: hierarchy]

Inside `ArControlador` are the markers. Inside `Canvas` are the toggles.

But, actually I build this project in rude way, getting each element with `GameObject.Find`. I want get the GameObjects in in elegance way, clean code and it can be scaleable.

I want get the GameObjects in an automated way, so if I have 3, 5, 10 or 20 elements the code will run perfectly.

I think in some possibilities like `Array` of `GameObjects`, `List` of `GameObjects`, create a `GameObject` father and get all childs like `FindGameObjectsWithTag` but I don't have successfull.

This is my code, it already works but in rude way, geting `GameObject` per `GameObject` and enable/disable the GameObjects with `aux` variable, see:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class AlternaEntreOsPassos : MonoBehaviour
{
    private UnityEngine.UI.Toggle[] toggles;
    public int aux = 0;

    public GameObject marker1, marker2, marker3;

        void Awake()
    {
        //Find manually the objects
        marker1 = GameObject.Find("Marcador1");
        marker2 = GameObject.Find("Marcador2");
        marker3 = GameObject.Find("Marcador3");
    }


    void Start()
    {
        toggles = GetComponentsInChildren<UnityEngine.UI.Toggle>();


        if (toggles.Length > 0)
        {

            //2nd and 3rd false for not be displayed yet...
            marker2.SetActive(false);
            marker3.SetActive(false);

            for (int i = 0; i < toggles.Length; i++)
            {

                int closureIndex = i;               
                toggles[closureIndex].interactable = false;
                toggles[closureIndex].onValueChanged.AddListener((isOn) =>
                {
                    if (isOn == true)
                    {
                        aux++;

                        //Disabling the toggle that was clicked
                        toggles[closureIndex].interactable = false;

                        if (closureIndex < toggles.Length - 1)
                        {
                            //Activatin the next toggle
                            toggles[closureIndex + 1].interactable = true;                           
                        }

                        if (aux == 1)
                        {
                            //Desactivating the actual element and activating the next element
                            marker1.SetActive(false);
                            marker2.SetActive(true);
                        }

                        if (aux == 2)
                        {
                            //Desactivating the actual element and activating the next element
                            marker2.SetActive(false);
                            marker3.SetActive(true);
                        }

                        if (aux == 3)
                        {
                            marker3.SetActive(false);
                        }

                    }
                }
            );

            }

            toggles[0].interactable = true;
        }     
    }
}
```

So, how I can get the `GameObjects` in intelligent way like the examples above (`array`, `list`, `tag`) or something else.

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the transform hierarchy. You've already got your step1, step2, step3... objects assigned to a parent.

```
List<GameObject> steps = new List<GameObject>();

void Awake() {
    GameObject parentObject = GameObject.Find("Steps");
    for(int i = 0; i < parentObject.transform.childCount; i++) {
        steps.Add(parentObject.transform.GetChild(i));
    }
}
```